# Update CiviCRM with composer fails during patching: "Cannot apply patch Allow single quotes to be used in return path"

Tags: upgrade, composer

Currently on CiviCRM 5.51.1 with Drupal 9.4.3 and PHP 8.0. I wanted to update CiviCRM but no matter if I try to update to 5.51.3 or 5.52 - I get the composer error:

```
 Applying patches for zetacomponents/mail
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch (CiviCRM Custom Patches for ZetaCompoents mail)
    https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch (Allow single quotes to be used in return path)
   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch

In Patches.php line 326:

  Cannot apply patch Allow single quotes to be used in return path (https://g
  ithub.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch)!
```

This is the composer.json with which I run composer update:

```
{
    "name": "abgeordnetenwatch/civicrm",
    "description": "This composer.json is based on the composer.json of drupal-composer/drupal-project and meets the needs of our CiviCRM installaion",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Tobias Krause",
            "role": "Lead developer",
            "email": "krause@abgeordnetenwatch.de"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": "~1.0",
        "civicrm/civicrm-core": "^5.50.0",
        "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "^5.50.0",
        "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "^5.50.0",
        "civicrm/cv": "^0.3.20",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
        "drupal/civicrm_drush": "^1.2",
        "drupal/config_split": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.4",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.4",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.6",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.1",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9.4",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "discard-changes": true,
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "civicrm/composer-compile-plugin": true,
            "civicrm/composer-downloads-plugin": true,
            "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["httpdocs/load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "httpdocs/"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
                "[web-root]/robots.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/development.services.yml": false,
                "[web-root]/INSTALL.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/README.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/example.gitignore": false,
                "[web-root]/.htaccess": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/default/settings.php": false
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "httpdocs/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "httpdocs/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "httpdocs/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "httpdocs/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "httpdocs/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "patches": {
        },
        "civicrm-asset": {
            "path": "httpdocs/libraries/civicrm",
            "url": "/libraries/civicrm",
            "assets:core": {
                "include": ["js/**", "css/**", "ang/**", "templates/**.png", "templates/**.jpg", "ext/ckeditor4/js/ck-options.json"],
                "exclude-dir": [".git", "/CRM"]
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": "true",
        "compile-whitelist": ["civicrm/civicrm-core", "civicrm/composer-compile-lib"]
    }
}
```

One week ago I just used the same composer.json with composer update without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there were patches being applied for php 8.1 compatibility but they are now in the original package so the patches aren't needed anymore.

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24198

Comment: ah... thank you for this info

Comment: This pull request is against 5.53. What about updating 5.51 or 5.52? Or will this get into the next 5.51.x and 5.52.x release anyway?

Comment: 5.52 backport is merged. There likely won't be one for 5.51 since it's annoying but not critical.

Comment: Thank you for this... unfortunately this worked now for me locally and in our dev environment but on production I still get this error. Do you have any idea why the exact same composer.json works on dev but not on production? PHP version and composer version are the same