# Composer Drupal Update fails because unappliable Patch of Civicrms zetacomponents/mail

Tags: email, upgrade, composer, failure

I try to update a Drupalmachine on 9.4.5 site via composer 2.4.1.
`~/bin/composer.phar update drupal/core "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies` (see below for composer.json)

first try i can run it and get into interactive question that drupal/coder has multiple files changed (439) and what i want to do:

```
y - discard changes and apply the update
n - abort the update and let you manually clean things up
v - view modified files
d - view local modifications (diff)
s - stash changes and try to reapply them after the update
? - print help
```

i try to choose 'yes', but unfortunately i ran into a problem that patch 86 from zetacomponents/mail can not be applied and the update crashed. This patch seemed to be [merged](https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86) and old
composer try to install zetamail in version 1.9.3.
I tried to apply the patch manually on the files, but this
doesnt work either.

Here is the shortend version of the run through the update to the  error. After gathering the patches it got this errormessage, that the patches doesnt apply.

```
Applying patches for zetacomponents/mail
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch (CiviCRM Custom Patches for ZetaCompoents mail)
    https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch (Allow single quotes to be used in return path)
   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch

In Patches.php line 326:
                                                                                                                            
  Cannot apply patch Allow single quotes to be used in return path (https://github.com/zetacomponents/Mail/pull/86.patch)!
```

Like suggested I provide the composer.json:

```
{
  "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
  "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "role": ""
    }
  ],
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.8",
    "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": "~1.1",
    "civicrm/civicrm-core": "5.49.4",
    "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "5.49.4",
    "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "5.49.4",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
    "drupal/civicrm_entity": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
    "drupal/content_access": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/context": "^4.1",
    "drupal/core": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.2",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
    "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/role_delegation": "^1.1",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/token": "^1.10",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.12",
    "drupal/views_aggregator": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.1",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
    "drupal/webform_civicrm": "^6.0",
    "drush/drush": "^9.7.1 | ^10.0.0",
    "howtomakeaturn/pdfinfo": "1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.0",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^9"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true,
      "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
      "civicrm/composer-compile-plugin": true,
      "civicrm/composer-downloads-plugin": true,
      "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": true,
      "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
      "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
      "drupal/core-project-message": true,
      "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true,
      "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ],
    "files": [
      "load.environment.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patchLevel": {
      "drupal/core": "-p2"
    },
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
      }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/core": [
        "type:drupal-core"
      ],
      "web/libraries/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-library"
      ],
      "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-module"
      ],
      "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-profile"
      ],
      "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-theme"
      ],
      "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-drush"
      ]
    },
    "civicrm-asset": {
      "path": "web/libraries/civicrm",
      "url": "/libraries/civicrm",
      "assets:packages": {
        "+include": [
          "kcfinder/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "enable-patching": "true",
    "compile-whitelist": [
      "civicrm/civicrm-core",
      "civicrm/composer-compile-lib"
    ],
    "compile-mode": "all"
  }
}
```

I it save to try `"composer-exit-on-patch-failure": false` or is that safe? I find this question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42439/update-civicrm-with-composer-fails-during-patching-cannot-apply-patch-allow-si) but there is the Answer that the Patch is  not important anymore, but no
statement how to get around the Error. Also I am stuck at a place that that the update
fail, regardless of the use of `composer upgrade` or `composer update`, i cant
get to the [y,n,v,d,s,?] decision anymore.
Is there a method to get the update done?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I keep getting this error but strangely only on our production environment. For all local development versions as well as for the dev/stage remote version this problem does not appear. we just updated to CiviCRM 5.54 but the issue still exists.

Comment: I used to upgrade civi as @demerit suggested, then i updated drupal. The civi update removes the old zeta patch and then the drupal update works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade civi to 5.52+ then do that.

If not you could restrict zeta mail to an earlier version, e.g. `composer require zetacomponents/mail:1.9.2`, but then remember to remove that from composer.json when you do upgrade civi later.